# how to remove white space inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to remove top, button, left and right space around the Date text?
I want to make the div only contain text without any space and still responsive

```css
.fit {
    width: fit-content;
    /* To adjust the height as well */
    height: fit-content;
}
#Topspace {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div  id="Topspace" >
<div class="well col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

    <div class=" fit well col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:grey;margin-top:-50px;">
        <p class="" style="word-wrap: break-word;
">DD/MM/YY</p>
    </div>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a [CSS Reset](https://cssreset.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, just i use background-color and border for the pragragh

```css
.fit{ width: fit-content; 
  /* To adjust the height as well */ 
  height: fit-content;}</style>
```

```html
<p class=" fit" style="background-color:grey;word-wrap: break-word;border:solid;border-color:grey">
3/feb/2018
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

"I want to make the div only contain text without any space and still responsive."

which div? what if you remove this from the third div?

```
margin-top:-50px;
```

is that what you need? it's hard to tell from your question.

Answer (score 0):

just try setting the `max-width` of the container div

```
.fit.well {
padding: 0;
max-width: 30px;
}
```

```css
.fit {
    width: fit-content;
    /* To adjust the height as well */
    height: fit-content;
}
#Topspace {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.fit.well {
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div  id="Topspace" >
<div class="well col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">

    <div class=" fit well col-sm-3 col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:grey;margin-top:-50px;">
        <p class="" style="word-wrap: break-word;
">DD/MM/YY</p>
    </div>


</div>
</div>
```